# Inequalities in matrix norm.

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

My book says, for any $t$
$e^
{tA} = C diag(e^
{tJ_1}
,··· , e^
{tJ_k} ) C^{
−1}$
.
Hence,$
|e^
{tA}
| ≤ |diag(e^
{tJ_1}
,··· , e^
{tJ_k} )
|$

Where $J_i$ are exponential of jordan blocks of A.

I didn't understand why this has to be true.please help

|A| here denote induced p norm of A

Comment: Does $|e^{ta}|$ mean determinant of $e^{tA}$, or norm?

Comment: It means norm, I will edit it sorry

Comment: which statement is unclear? $e^{t A} = C \operatorname{diag}(...) C^{-1}$? In that case use the series definition of matrix exponential.

Comment: I am not sure if the norm inequality is correct in general. it feels weird to me. It is true, if $A$ is normal and $p=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true in general: all you can say is
$$ |e^{tA}| \le |C| |C^{-1}| |\text{diag}(e^{t J_1},\ldots,e^{t J_k})|$$
but there's no reason to think $|C| |C^{-1}| = 1$.

You might try some $2 \times 2$ (non-normal) examples.  The computations can get rather messy, but you should find that the inequality is false most of the time.

One fairly simple example is
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 2\cr -1 & -1\cr}$$
This has eigenvalues $\pm i$, and $|e^{tJ}| = 1$ for all $t$.  But
$$ \exp(tA) = \pmatrix{\cos(t)+\sin(t) & 2 \sin(t)\cr -\sin(t) & \cos(t) - \sin(t) \cr}$$
and since $2 \sin(t)$ can be as much as $2$, it is evident that $|\exp(tA)|$ can be at least $2$.  Indeed, for $t=\pi/2$ the norm turns out to be $\sqrt{7/2 + 3 \sqrt{5}/2} \approx 2.618$.